# Custom List Search Box - Search for ID Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

I am wondering why the list search box (nearby the view selection, just on top of my custom list) does not find items by ID column. Is there something that needs be be done before? I don´t need the site search etc. to find or crawl items ID but the listpart searchbox should search in every field? Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'ListItemID:1394'  or create new [Result Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/us-en/library/dn186229.aspx)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/b965aae8-0eb8-42ab-888c-95ce340fe0ef/sharepoint-2013-search-list-item-with-item-id

Comment: Are there any pros or cons to adding the ListItemID as a Result Source? Has anyone else done this before?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom search SharePoint list

Add the content editor web part of your share point list 
and add the script

Configure which column you want to use as title column

Code is below:

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function RedirectUrl()
     {
         var tb = document.getElementById("tbSearch").value;
         if(tb != null)
         {
             window.location.href="?FilterName=Title&FilterMultiValue=*"+tb.trim()+"*";
         }
         return false;
    };

    function ClearUrl()
    {
        window.location.href="?FilterName=Title&FilterMultiValue=**";
    } 
</script>
```

HTML

```
<p> Search for Doc Name
    <input id="tbSearch" type="text"/> 
    <input id="btnSearch" onclick="return RedirectUrl();" type="submit" value="Search"/> 
    <input id="btnSearch" onclick="return ClearUrl();" type="button" value="Clear"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;<i>Partial document number allowed!</i>
</p>

<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">VQKAZZPE22SS-1-67</mso:_dlc_DocId>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">e91c3715-743e-42dc-a138-4eb411fa53f5</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">https://teamsites.nafta.fcagroup.com/sites/gp/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=VQKAZZPE22SS-1-67, VQKAZZPE22SS-1-67</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
/</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
```